# Заменить текст в элементе содержащего другие элементы

Tags: jquery

есть код

```html
<div id="master">
  <div>этот текст нельзя менять</div>
  этот текст нужно заменить
  <div>и этот текст нельзя менять</div>
</div>
```

нужно изменить текст между тегами div , как это можно сделать без помощи метода $("селектор").**html**() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как единственное условие в вопросе:

> между тегами div

```js
var children = document.getElementById("master").childNodes;
for(var i = 1; i < children.length - 1; i++) {
  if (children[i - 1].nodeName == "DIV" && 
      children[i + 1].nodeName == "DIV" &&
      children[i].nodeType == 3) {
    children[i].textContent = "заменил, заменил, заменил";
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="master">
  <div>этот текст нельзя менять</div>
  этот текст нужно заменить
  <div>и этот текст нельзя менять</div>
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю. ваш пример рабочий

Answer (score 0):

Метод доведен не до конца, но с дивами будет работать

```
var some_text = 'Это изменённый текст';        
document.querySelector('#master').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#master').innerHTML
                                            .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
                                            .replace(/<\/[\w]+\>(.*?)<[\w]+[^>]*>/, function () {
                                                return '</div>' + some_text + '<div>';
                                            });
```